# Converting age group ranges into numeric values

Tags: r, data-conversion, categorical-data

I'm working with a dataset and want to use ordinal regression model to analyze the data. One of the independent variable is Age with ranges: 18-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55-64,and  65+ .

I tried to convert it into numeric values using as.numeric function but keep geting a warning message saying "NAs introduced by coercion". I tried gsub but there are no commas in my dataset. Could someone please tell me how I can convert the age ranges into numeric values?

Comment: Using `dplyr` you can use `df %>% group_by(Age) %>% mutate(age_id = cur_group_id())`. First it groups your age ranges in "Age", then it makes a new "age_id" column and gives each group an integer value.

Comment: I get a warning message saying "could not find function "%>%"

Comment: You need to load dplyr first by running `library(dplyr)` or `library(tidyverse)`.

Comment: For ordinal regression, you typically want to convert the response variable to an **ordered factor**, rather than to numeric ...

Comment: Thank you! the grouping thing worked. Is it possible to give an id to multiple categorical variables from the same data? And how do I include the new column into my dataframe?

Comment: I figured it out :) but all the new grouped columns have same integer values (1-6) making it difficult to interpret. Is there a way to fix that?